# representing 2 different metrics with different columns in line chart

Tags: looker-studio

I am preparing a datastudio report.  The data studio report consists of the following columns below:

[image]

As seen in the picture it captures metric data at a particular **time**.

```
The date range is set as the end_time
```

The X axis will represent the **end_time** column and the breakdown dimension will be **InstanceName**  column and I am preparing to show it as line chart.

`There are 2 metrics` **readops** and **writeops** columns.

`I need to represent these 2 metrics as 2 different lines in the same chart so that the read and write operation fluctuations for the instance at a particular time can be easily viewed.`

I am not sure on how to represent this on data studio. If it is 1 metrics, i know it is straight forward. I can set **instancename** as **breakdown** dimension and **end_time** as dimension and **date range** is set to end_time and can represent it. But to represent the 2 metrics as 2 different lines for a particular Instance, with the time range on x axis, i don't know as I am very new to datastudio. I want to do it without drill-down. similar to the picture below which I got from google cloud console which shows **ReadBytes** the Big Triangle and the smaller one at the bottom in **red** for **WriteBytes**
[image]
Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches based on how the the charts need to be displayed:

### 1) [Filter Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144)

If the aim is to only display 2 lines (2 Metrics):

- `readops`
- `writeops`

While allowing the user to select the required `InstanceName`, then a Filter Control (optionally with a default selection) could be used.

The chart would be set up using:

- ***Dimension***: `end_time`
- ***Metric #1***: `readops`
- ***Metric #2***: `writeops`

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/16d383eb-2dda-44aa-9fd1-2c7bf528009c) and a GIF to expand on the above:

[image]

### 2) Multiple Metrics

If the objective is to display a line for each of the `InstanceName` values as well as both the Metrics (`readops` and `writeops`), then the below approach would be one way.

Currently, when using a Breakdown Dimension, Google Data Studio charts (such as a [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) chart) support a single metric.

Using the Data Set below, based on the screenshot in the question ([Editable Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d7hZKqZGXX5ay6urLAGSkLkK5yOWWqAgNyoiWi_U48U/edit?usp=sharing)):

[image]

One approach is to create and use multiple [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statements at the Data Source; for example:

1. `readops_dum`

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(InstanceName, "(dum)") THEN readops
  ELSE NULL
END
```

2. `writeops_dum`

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(InstanceName, "(dum)") THEN writeops
  ELSE NULL
END
```

etc...

[Editable Google Data Studio Data Source](https://datastudio.google.com/datasources/a3bcd0c6-3133-40ea-a502-8524951679cf) and an image to elaborate:

[image]

A Chart could then be created with `end_time` as the Dimension and using the newly created Metrics; [Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/16d383eb-2dda-44aa-9fd1-2c7bf528009c/page/jTgaB) and an image to visualise with a [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) chart:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have a set of dynamic instances, so for each dynamic instance  a entry should be made against the readops and writeops. So the metrics you created for the instancename to appear should be dynamic and I dont want to hard coat it as a field.  Can you please tell me how to achieve that?

Comment: for the first solution you proposed using filter control , when I select the InstanceName in filter control , is it possible to show that same value, as a label in some other place near the chart? For example if the filter control is not having any value by default, i want the label to display as All Instances?